# Celery + Django on startup

Tags: python, django, apache, celery

I have written a code with django and celery, it is for a machine to run some tasks and to be accessible through net. So I need the django and celery to run automatically when the built-in PC starts. Can anyone please tell me the best and easiest way to do this? Can servers like Apache handle such thing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if anyone has this problem, first I wrote a .sh file for each one and then call them in start up setting in ubuntu.